# CKEditor: can't type in editor field

Tags: types, ckeditor, textfield

I'm using CKEditor, but I can't type any text into the field, nor can I use any menu items.
I'm loading the editor using this code:

```
<textarea name="editor_beschreibung"></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor_beschreibung');
</script>
```

This is how my config looks:

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2015, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or http://ckeditor.com/license
 */

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 // Define changes to default configuration here.
 // For complete reference see:
 // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

 // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
 config.toolbarGroups = [
  { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
  { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
  { name: 'links' },
  { name: 'insert' },
  { name: 'forms' },
  { name: 'tools' },
  { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
  { name: 'others' },
  '/',
  { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
  { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
  { name: 'styles' },
  { name: 'colors' },
  { name: 'about' }
 ];

 // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
 // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
 config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

 // Set the most common block elements.
 config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

 // Simplify the dialog windows.
 config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
 
 //size
 config.height = '450px';
 
 config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
};
```

I hope that someone can help me to fix this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Do you run it in a dialog or some sort of modal?

Comment: I just ran it inside an HTML page. After redownloading the editor package it worked fine. Must be some sort of misconfiguration

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the same problem. Here is a possibly relevant solution (which does not work for me though): https://processwire.com/talk/topic/8150-cant-type-into-ckeditor-when-its-blank-chrome-only/